# In jQuery How do turn a subset of checkboxes on and off based on another checkbox

Tags: jquery

I have a list of divisions and subdivisions that I show with checkboxes, dynamically created through a database with the end result somewhat like this:

```
<input name="divisions[]" type="checkbox" value "division1"/> Division One
    <input name="departments[]" type="checkbox" value "department1"/> Department One
    <input name="departments[]" type="checkbox" value "department2"/> Department Two

<input name="divisions[]" type="checkbox" value "division2"/> Division Two
    <input name="departments[]" type="checkbox" value "department3"/> Department Three
    <input name="departments[]" type="checkbox" value "department4"/> Department Four
```

I need to write the jQuery code such when the user clicks on the a division all of its departments and only its departments are equally clicked on or off.

I was thinking of attaching a clicked event function to all divisions that turned on or off all the immediate departments, though I don't know the syntax:
conceptually I was thinking:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $(all_elements_with_the_name_divisions).click(function() {
        $(all_immediately_following_elements_with_the_name_departments).attr('checked',this.checked);
    });
})
```

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick.

```
<input type="checkbox" class="divisions" value="division1" />
<input type="checkbox" class="division1_departments" value="division1_departmen1" />
<input type="checkbox" class="division1_departments" value="division1_departmen2" />
<input type="checkbox" class="divisions" value="division2" />
<input type="checkbox" class="division2_departments" value="division2_departmen1" />
<input type="checkbox" class="division2_departments" value="division2_departmen2" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("input.divisions:checkbox").click(function () {
            $("input." + $(this).val() + "_departments:checkbox").attr("checked", $(this).is(':checked'));
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: very nice, assigning classes to both categories. - thank you. I was wondering if there's a jQuery syntax for "immediately following"?

Comment: There is but I can't recommend using it in this context. Having functionality code depend on the HTML layout is very smelly. If you're dead set on going about it that way though take a look at the `siblings()` call.

Comment: At the end of the day, this solution worked best for me, because after organizing css on the page I ended up with divs for placement which negated the sibling concept. - thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

If you surround each group in a `<div>` you can use the [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

```
<div>
  <input name="divisions[]" type="checkbox" value "division1"/> Division One
  <input name="departments[]" type="checkbox" value "department1"/> Department One
  <input name="departments[]" type="checkbox" value "department2"/> Department Two
</div>
<div>
  <input name="divisions[]" type="checkbox" value "division2"/> Division Two
  <input name="departments[]" type="checkbox" value "department3"/> Department Three
  <input name="departments[]" type="checkbox" value "department4"/> Department Four
</div>


jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[name="divisions\\[\\]"]').click(function() {
        $(this).siblings('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked',this.checked);
    });
})
```

Comment: good thought! and how would I identify the divisions? $('input[name="division"]') ? would that work for a form array?

Answer (score 1):

If you were able to structure your markup like this:

```
<div class="division">
    <input name="divisions[]" type="checkbox" value "division1"/> Division One
        <div class="department">
        <input name="departments[]" type="checkbox" value "department1"/> Department One
        <input name="departments[]" type="checkbox" value "department2"/> Department Two
        </div>
</div>
```

The following code should do what you want:

```
$('.division input[name="divisions\\[\\]"]').click(function() { 
    $(this).find('.department input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked', this.checked);
});
```

Comment: thanks, I was wondering how to reference the name of a form array.